# How to get data from div class data using simple dom parser?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the pic id and description from a class

```
<div class="pic" style="top:0px;left:0px;height:149px;" data= 
{"pic_id":"06e50224ab189";}" pic-descr=" this title " data-index="0">

....

</div>
```

how to find and get `pic_id` data and `pic-descr` ?

Comment: It might not look like much but this question is actually pretty instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting because it looks like pic_id is broken json. We can still get the data with a regex:

```
$str = <<<EOF
<div class="pic" style="top:0px;left:0px;height:149px;" data='{"pic_id":"06e50224ab189";}' pic-descr=" this title " data-index="0">
</div>
EOF;

$html = str_get_html($str);
$div = $html->find('.pic', 0);

if(preg_match('/:"(.*?)"/', $div->data, $m)){
  echo "pic_id is: " . $m[1] . "\n";
}
echo "pic-descr is: " . $div->{'pic-descr'} . "\n";
```

If the json were not broken you could do:
`json_decode($div->data)->pic_id`

Comment: I understand OP tagged this `simple-html-dom`, but just to confirm, `str_get_html` is not native PHP builtin right? is it part of this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/  ?